# Get currently playing audio filepath in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to obtain a URI of currently played audio track? I already registered for intent of METACHANGED but "intent.getData()" returns null instead of the URI. Is there any other way?

Comment: Note that it may be a stream from Internet

Comment: Agreed. What makes you think that there *is* a `Uri` for any possible audio being played?

Comment: I used mine audio file from SD card. If it is a stream from the Internet null will be fine as a result but I'm sure that the file is located on the external storage during my test and get data() still returns null. Why?